# How to simplify $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\tau) {\operatorname{sinc}}\big({\tau}-\lambda\big) {\operatorname{sinc}}\big({\tau}-\nu\big)d\tau$

Tags: fourier-analysis

Prove that, for any real numbers $\lambda$ and $\nu$, one has
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\tau) {\operatorname{sinc}}\big({\tau}-\lambda\big) {\operatorname{sinc}}\big({\tau}-\nu\big)d\tau=\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{F(\omega_1+\omega_2)e^{j(\omega_1\lambda+\omega_2\nu)}d\omega_1d\omega_2}$$
where $F(\omega)$ is the Fourier transform of $f(t)$.

Afterward, calculate:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\tau) {\operatorname{sinc}}\big({\tau}-\lambda\big) {\operatorname{sinc}}\big({\tau}-\nu\big)d\tau$$
for $f(t)=\sin(\omega_0t)$.

In particular, I do not know how to prove the first formula. Suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inverse Fourier transform of $a(\tau)=\text{sinc}(\tau-\lambda)$ is given by a constant times $e^{-\lambda i \xi}\cdot \mathbb{1}_{\xi\in(-1,1)} $.
If we set $b(\tau)=\text{sinc}(\tau-\nu)$, from $\mathcal{F}(a\cdot b)=\mathcal{F}(a)*\mathcal{F}(b)$ we get that the inverse Fourier transform of $a(\tau)\cdot b(\tau)$ is given by a constant times:
$$ e^{-\frac{\nu+\lambda}{2}i\xi}\cdot\sin\left(1-\frac{\xi}{2}\,\text{sign}(\xi)\right)\cdot \mathbb{1}_{\xi\in(-2,2)}.$$
By rearranging a bit and exploiting:
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(\tau)\cdot a(\tau)b(\tau)\,d\tau = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathcal{F}(f)(\xi)\cdot \mathcal{F}^{-1}(a\cdot b)(\xi)\,d\xi $$
the claim follows. I leave the second part to you: the Fourier transform of $\sin(\omega_0 \tau)$ is just the difference of two Dirac delta function multiplied by a constant.

Comment: Thank you @Jack! Could you add some other steps? Excuse me but I'm not expert on Fourier Analysis. For $\omega_0\in[0,2\pi]$, I found this: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\sin(\omega_0\tau) \operatorname{sinc}(\tau-\lambda) \operatorname{sinc}(\tau-\nu)d\tau }=\frac{1}{2\pi(\nu-\lambda)}\left\{\sin[\pi(\nu-\lambda)+\omega_0\lambda ]-\sin[\pi(\nu-\lambda)-\omega_0\nu ]\right\},$$ instead, for $\omega_0\geq 2\pi$, result is $0$. Is it true?

Comment: @Lely: I am not 100% sure about the constants, but it should be right.